# JS: Bookmarklet - Create a bookmarklet that fires a local js file to fill up fields in a form of the current page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, bookmarklet

I'm trying to create a bookmarklet that fills up fields on the form of my current page.

Here's a simple script that fills up 1 field with a given value:

```
javascript:(function(){d=document;e=d.getElementById("ember469");e.value="dummy3@restricted.com";e.blur();})();
```

This is working properly if I store is as a bookmark. Now I want to store this JS on a local file in my machine because I'd like to fill up X number of fields and I dont want to maintain the code from within the bookmarklet.

I tried creating a bookmarklet that calls my local js "test.js" using:

```
javascript:(function(){var js=document.createElement('script');js.setAttribute('src', 'C:/Users/path/to/my/sample.js');document.body.appendChild(js);}());
```

I got this idea from these links:
[Link 1](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-bookmarklets-the-right-way--net-18154)
[Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24126438/make-a-bookmarklet-execute-a-function-that-it-downloads)

Here's my sample.js contents:

```
function(){d=document;e=d.getElementById("ember469");e.value="dummy3@restricted.com";e.blur();}
```

I've looked around SO but I can't find a sample that loads a local js, most samples are loading an online js file.

I'm unable to make this work. What am I missing?

Any help is appreciated!!

**UPDATE:**
Based on @Shugar's answer below, I've updated both my sample.js and bookmarklet. I can see the script tag getting inserted on the page but that script doesnt fire. The field isn't getting populated.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope the following way will work for you. (Just edited the posted code a little.)

**Bookmarklet:**

```
javascript: (function() {
    var js = document.createElement('script');
    js.setAttribute('src', 'C:/Users/path/to/my/sample.js');
    document.body.appendChild(js);
})();
```

**sample.js:**

```
(function() {
    d = document;
    e = d.getElementById("ember469");
    e.value = "dummy3@restricted.com";
    e.blur();
})();
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! I have updated my question with the results. I can see the script tag getting inserted but the sample.js isn't getting fired - the field is not getting filled.

Comment: Hi, are you sure that the actions from the 'sample.js' are not getting fired? Try to add the first line such as `alert("From 'sample.js'");` in your anonymous function. It seems to me that the id's like "ember469" are just changed on the web page.

Comment: Yes. I did check the element. Just now I tried with a sample alert like you suggested and even that didnt work. Really am wondering what I am missing.

Comment: Try to open the web console in Chrome (Ctrl+Shift+I) and take a look at the errors occurred.

Comment: Wow! thanks for that tip. I'm getting this error: `Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C:/Users/..../sample.js` I'm gonna go look this up.

Comment: I'm gonna go ahead and accept this answer if I manage to do it from my personal pc. Workplace security policies prevent me from making any sort of changes on google chrome to bypass this issue and test it out. Thanks again!

Comment: Yes, that does work only if the web page is a local file... I believe you simply need more professional tool for web automation. There are a lot of options, for example, ['iMacros'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/imacros) (free extensions for [Chrome](http://wiki.imacros.net/iMacros_for_Chrome) and [Firefox](http://wiki.imacros.net/Firefox)). It's quite enough for many people to do amazing things! Hope 'iMacros' will be helpful to you as well.

Comment: Thanks for the tip but I do have my reasons on why I want to do it via a bookmarklet. e.g. - workplace security with installin applications, with installing browser plugins etc.